# openSUSE-2022-10067 - Failed to open a session for the virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, opensuse

After installing openSUSE-2022-10067 Security update for virtualbox, I got the following error when trying to start a guest vitural machine: Failed to open a session for the virtual machine. Result Code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component: SessionMachine Interface: ISession{c0447716-ff5a-4795-b57a-ecd5fffa18a4}
Details: The VM Session was aborted.

I had above errors with MS Win-10 and Opensuse Leap 15.4 Guest VM's on a Open Suse Leap 15.4 VM-Host-System.

Anybody experiances the same issue?
My temporary solution was to rollback the snapshot to pre-installation of the security update for virtualbox. Then it was possible to start the VM's without any errors again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've seen a similar crash when trying to start a VM with the combination of VirtualBox 6.1.35 and 6.1.36 in combination with the VirtualBox Extension Pack (EP) 6.1.34. Did you also upgrade the EP? ;)
This solves my problem in VirtualBox 6.1.36
With 6.1.35 I could not even update the EP without running in the same error.
Hope this helps.
BR Markus